# Replicate Photoshop adjustment layer in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, photoshop

Is there anyway we can replicate Photoshop's adjustment layer in Flash?
I see that we can replicate blend like overlay.
But didn't see a way to replicate Hue/Saturation adjustment layer for example.

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `ColorMatrixFilter` - not sure if it will render exactly the same, but here a sample you can try:

```
var colorFilter:AdjustColor = new AdjustColor();
var mColorMatrix:ColorMatrixFilter;
var mMatrix:Array = [];
var MC:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

function adjustColors():void
{
    //all 4 must contain a value of an integer, if one is not set, it will not work
    colorFilter.hue = 50;
    colorFilter.saturation = 50;
    colorFilter.brightness = 50;
    colorFilter.contrast = 0;

    mMatrix = colorFilter.CalculateFinalFlatArray();
    mColorMatrix = new ColorMatrixFilter(mMatrix);

    MC.filters = [mColorMatrix];
}
```

Comment: Hello people, I've been fighting with this problem as well and so far no attempts have achieved the desired results.  I've tried the suggestion above (used Flash CS6 to do a quick test using the AdjustColor filter on a MovieClip that I pasted in a layer from Photoshop, the hue adjustment isn't the same).  I've also tried the ColorMatrix class from Grant Skinner and the quasimondo one (each has it's own "lightness" factors that seem to be related to the issue).  I've tried educating myself on color spaces, but am still struggling to figure out what Photoshop does with it's hue adjustment layer.

Answer (score 0):

True North Creative's answer will work if you take the AS3 route, but you would probably have more control and efficiency if you create/use Pixel Bender filters instead.

more here:  http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pixelbender.html